# How can I use "for" inside an "array"?

Tags: php, json, for-loop, export-to-csv

Thank you for your help.
I am working on a new site, i would love to generate a CSV from a XML website.
But i can't use "for (number...)" inside an array.

```
<?php
  // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
  header('Content-type: text/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="demo.csv"');

  // do not cache the file
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header('Expires: 0');

  // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
  $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

  // send the column headers
  fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

  $json_string = "http://v2.notmaison.be/php/index.php?action=getRealEstateByNotaris&notaris=FRANCE,%20Gilles";
  $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
  $result = json_decode ($jsondata,true);
  $nombre = count($result['results']);

  $json = $result['results'][$numero]['im'];
  $json_decoded = json_decode($json);
  $data = array(

    for ($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre ; $numero++) {
      Array($result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],"test2","test3")
    );
  }

  // output each row of the data
  foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);
  }

  exit();
?>
```

I have this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting ')' in /htdocs/biens3.php on line 25

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself.

Comment: Do you know a language where you can use `for` in an array?

Comment: I'm newbie, i'm sorry.

Comment: How can i convert this to CSV - http://v2.notmaison.be/php/index.php?action=getRealEstateByNotaris&notaris=FRANCE,%20Gilles ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
    for ($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre ; $numero++)
    {
        $data[] =   Array($result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],"test2","test3");
    }
```

Comment: Woof ! Thank you so much! I didn't know !

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring $data as an empty Array, then for each $nombre you add an item/Array to $data, something liek this:

```
$data = Array();

for($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre; $numero++){
    $data[] = Array($result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],"test2","test3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to populate the array, instead of this:

```
$data = array(

for ($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre ; $numero++)
{
    Array($result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],"test2","test3")
);
}
```

You can first  create the array like you're doing,  but just create, and
then add the elements with a loop:

```
$data = []; # shorter syntax than array(), but the same.

for ($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre ; $numero++)
{
    $data[] = [
        $result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ];
}
```

The syntax  `$data[]` will push elements  to the end of  the array. Note
that you  actually don't even  need to create  the array itself.  I also
noticed  that right  after you're  looping on  the array  to output  its
contents. And since you don't use `$data` anywhere else after, you could
eliminate it and ouptup data in the same loop:

```
for ($numero = 0; $numero < $nombre ; $numero++)
{
    fputcsv($file, [
        $result['results'][$numero]['re_ru'],
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ]);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect candidate for the use of `foreach` rather than a `for`

The code can be simplified down to this

```
$json_string = "http://v2.notmaison.be/php/index.php?action=getRealEstateByNotaris&notaris=FRANCE,%20Gilles";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$json_obj = json_decode ($jsondata);

$csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ( $json_obj->results as $result) {
    // to use all the fields from the json returned
    fputcsv($csv_file, (array)$result);
}
```

Giving output:

```
25174,CH-82691-16,0,50.4107048,4.4445519,2,12,1,,3,4,,"Appartement meublé (3ème étage) 2 chambres avec cave et garage.<br/>Hall, séjour, cuisine équipée, sdb, wc, buanderie, 2 chambres.<br/>Balcon avant avec tente solaire. Porte blindée. Cave. Garage. Ascenseur.<br/>",,6000,2,0,-1,95000,10,"Rue Basslé",Charleroi,0,1,0,1,-1,-1,1018,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 95000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe B",201611231147,201611281115,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20161109022084,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,2,Appartements,"un appartement",12,Appartement,Appartement,2,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,3,Central,4,Equipée,"[""WEBB-AFYESF"",""WEBB-AFYES7"",""WEBB-AFYES9""]",238
22691,CH-82112-16,0,50.4234543,4.4862727,1,8,1,,9,2,,"Maison de rapport avec 2 appartements.<br/>Hall commun de +/- 16 m².<br/>Appartement rez (+/- 45 m²): chambre (+/- 18 m²), séjour-sàm (+/- 10 m²), cuisine (+/- 4 m²), sdb (+/- 2,5 m²), cour arrière.<br/>Appartement 1er étage (+/- 51 m²): séjour-sàm (+/- 29 m²), chambre (+/- 17 m²), sdb (+/- 3 m²).<br/>Grenier aménageable (+/- 70 m²).<br/>Châssis SV.","Libre à l'acte.",6060,2,60,-1,80000,114,"Rue Hanoteau",Gilly,0,-1,0,0,1,-1,594,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,2,2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 80000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe E",201607191431,201607250944,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20160228005227,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",8,"Maison de rapport",Opbrengsteigendom,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,9,"Foyer gaz",2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-ABZGY2"",""WEBB-ABZGY5""]",238
15311,CH-80259-15,0,50.4291858,4.4990644,1,7,1,,5,2,,"Maison avec jardin.<br/>Sous-sol: cave.<br/>Rez: sàm, living.<br/>Annexe: cuisine, sdb avec wc séparé, buanderie.<br/>Etage: 2 chambres.<br/>Grenier, jardin.<br/>Châssis PVC double vitrage.",,6060,2,432,-1,55000,31,"Rue Brasserie Gillieaux",Gilly,0,-1,1,0,-1,-1,282,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 55000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe G",201509011601,201601060955,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,G,20150507024064,513,60394,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,5,"Central mazout",2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-9ZXJLP"",""WEBB-9ZXJLS"",""WEBB-9ZXJMS""]",238
24222,CH-82449-16,0,50.4276111,4.472657,4,39,1,,4,2,,"Immeuble de rapport avec commerce (et cour) au rez et 2 appartements.<br/>Sous-sol de 65 m².<br/>Rez commercial de 70 m²: commerce et pièce arrière avec WC. Cour.<br/>1er étage: appartement de 63 m² avec balcon: cuisine, séjour/sàm, hall, 1 chambre, sdb.<br/>2ème étage: appartement de 70 m² avec balcon: cuisine, séjour/sàm, débarras, hall, WC, sdb, 1 chambre.<br/>CC gaz, 3 chaudières séparées.<br/>citerne eau de pluie. Compteurs gaz et électricité séparés.",,6060,2,147,-1,160000,198,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart",Gilly,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,1682,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,2,-1,2,2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 160000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe G",201610101349,201610191534,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20161003008071,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,4,"Bureaux / Commerces","un bureau / commerce",39,"Maison de rapport",Opbrengsteigendom,4,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,4,"Central gaz",2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-AELG3S"",""WEBB-AEVHX6"",""WEBB-AEVHX8"",""WEBB-AEVHXA"",""WEBB-AEVHXC"",""WEBB-AEVHXE""]",238
24617,CH-82546-16,0,50.3780923,4.3711288,1,7,1,,4,1,5,"Sous-sol : caves<br/>Rez-de-chaussée (40 m²) : hall, séjour, cuisine<br/>1er étage (40m²) : hall, 2 chambres, salle de bain <br/>Grenier aménageable<br/>Jardin et cour<br/>Garage<br/>Chauffage central au gaz <br/>Châssis double vitrage PVC et aluminium<br/>R.C.: 431,00 €<br/>Superficie : 3 ares 30 centiares<br/>PEB  N° 20161020028100: classe E<br/>Faire offre à partir de 85.000,00 € . <br/>Offre actuelle : 85.000,00 €.<br/>                         <br/>",,6110,2,330,-1,85000,334,"Rue de Gozée",Montigny-le-Tilleul,3,-1,1,1,1,-1,431,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 85000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",0,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,,201610261444,201611080845,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20161020028100,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,5,Bon,4,"Central gaz",1,Présente,"[""WEBB-AF4H3P""]",238
25383,CH-82753-16,0,50.3439488,4.4577754,3,18,1,,,,,"Terrain de 9 ares 58ca.<br/>Lot sous teinte blanche.",,6120,0,958,-1,85000,,"Rue de la Ferrée",Nalinnes,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 85000 €","Sur place.",-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,,201612021139,201612021141,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,3,Terrains,"un terrain",18,"Prairies / pâtures",Weide,3,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,,,,,"[""WEBB-AG9EJM"",""WEBB-AG9EJP""]",238
18716,CH-81190-16,0,50.4239506,4.4872409,1,7,1,,5,2,,"Maison avec jardin.<br/>Sous-sol: cave avec voussettes.<br/>Rez: hall, séjour-sàm, WC.<br/>Annexe: cuisine, sdb.<br/>1er étage: hall, 3 chambres.<br/>Annexe au 1er étage: 1 chambre, WC, pièce.<br/>Grenier aménageable.<br/>Jardin à l'arrière. Châssis DV en partie et volets en partie.<br/>",,6060,4,220,-1,80000,11,"Rue de la Station",Gilly,0,-1,1,0,1,-1,773,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 80000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe G",201602050944,201608081422,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,G,20160128025502,528,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,5,"Central mazout",2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-A6UCCX"",""WEBB-A6UCCY"",""WEBB-A6UCD2""]",238
25159,CH-82686-16,0,50.4253111,4.501545,1,7,1,,,2,,"Maison 3 façades avec jardin.<br/>Sous-sol: caves.<br/>Rez: séjour, sàm avec coin cuisine, WC.<br/>1er étage: hall, 2 chambres.<br/>Grenier aménageable. Jardin.<br/>chauffage au charbon.<br/>Châssis DV PVC sauf un en façade.",,6060,2,350,-1,60000,47,"Rue de la Plateure",Gilly,3,-1,1,0,1,-1,297,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 60000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe G",201611221617,201611221625,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,201604280334591,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,,,2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-AFXL43"",""WEBB-AFXL4H""]",238
24585,CH-82540-16,0,50.422774,4.4799037,2,12,1,,4,4,,"Appartement (2ème étage) comprenant hall, séjour, cuisine (frigo, four électrique et hotte), sdb avec douche multi confort, chambre.<br/>Balcon arrière, cave.",,6060,1,0,-1,55000,5,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart",Gilly,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,706,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 55000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe F",201610251409,201610251416,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20161017025827,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,2,Appartements,"un appartement",12,Appartement,Appartement,2,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,4,"Central gaz",4,Equipée,"[""WEBB-AF3GDJ"",""WEBB-AF3GDL""]",238
22272,CH-82012-16,0,50.40205,4.5199634,1,7,1,,3,2,,"Maison avec dépendances et garage.<br/>Rez (+/- 50 m²): hall, cuisine, 1 pièce.<br/>1er étage (+/- 65 m²): hall, 4 chambres.<br/>2ème étage (+/- 60 m²): hall, sdb, 3 chambres.<br/>Grenier (+/- 45 m²) aménageable.<br/>Chauffage central, terrasse, jardin.<br/>RC du n°72: 535€ - RC du n°74: 97€.",,6200,7,228,-1,80000,72/74,"Rue d'Acoz",Châtelet,0,1,1,1,1,-1,632,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 80000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,"Classe G",201606291112,201606291117,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20160120016969,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,,,3,Central,2,"Non équipée","[""WEBB-ABDCWC"",""WEBB-ABDCWJ""]",238
22955,CH-82160-16,0,50.1681918,4.3181224,1,2,1,,9,4,5,"Châlet de 65m² meublé avec jardin comprenant :<br/> <br/>Living, cuisine, 2 chambres, salle de bains <br/>Jardin avec deux chalets <br/>Convecteurs pétrole avec thermostat<br/>Boiler au gaz <br/>PEB : F<br/>",,6440,2,280,-1,50000,314,"Parc Résidentiel Le Bosquet",Fourbechies,4,-1,1,0,-1,1,265,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 50000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,,201608081032,201608081036,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,20160707022876,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",2,Châlet,Chalet,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,,,5,Bon,9,"Foyer gaz",4,Equipée,"[""WEBB-ACMC4J"",""WEBB-ACMC4S"",""WEBB-ACMC4X""]",238
25119,CH-82675-16,0,50.4328324,4.467517,1,7,1,4,2,,3,"Maison incendiée 3 façades avec jardin composée de :<br/>Sous-sol : caves.<br/>Rez-de-chaussée : + 43m²<br/>1er étage: + 43m²<br/>Grenier aménageable<br/>Jardin <br/>Offres à partir de 60.000,00€<br/>Offre actuelle : 75.000,00 €<br/><br/><br/> <br/> <br/><br/>",,6060,1,367,-1,60000,111,"Rue Chausteur",Gilly,3,-1,1,0,1,0,609,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,"FRANCE, Gilles","Maison du notariat de Charleroi",071/41.45.34,071/20.56.56,"Faire offre à partir de: 60000 €","S'adresser en l'étude.",0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,201611210950,201612051553,contact@notairescharleroi.be,notaire.france@skynet.be,,,,,HA,,,,,OFF,,1,Maisons,"une maison",7,"Maison d'habitation",Woonhuis,1,1,Gré-à-Gré,4,Oui,3,Mauvais,2,"A installer",,,"[""WEBB-AFWCFT""]",238
```

Or if you only want specific fields from the json

```
$json_string = "http://v2.notmaison.be/php/index.php?action=getRealEstateByNotaris&notaris=FRANCE,%20Gilles";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$json_obj = json_decode ($jsondata);

$csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ( $json_obj->results as $result) {
    // to use only specific fields from the input
    fputcsv($csv_file, array($result->re_nu, $result->re_ru) );
}
```

Giving a csv like this

```
10,"Rue Basslé"
114,"Rue Hanoteau"
31,"Rue Brasserie Gillieaux"
198,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart"
334,"Rue de Gozée"
,"Rue de la Ferrée"
11,"Rue de la Station"
47,"Rue de la Plateure"
5,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart"
72/74,"Rue d'Acoz"
314,"Parc Résidentiel Le Bosquet"
111,"Rue Chausteur"
```

**EDIT for second question**

If you want the Images codes included in your output then this would do it

```
foreach ( $json_obj->results as $result) {
    $required = array();  // init an array

    // pick fields wanted in resulting csv
    $required[] = $result->re_nu;
    $required[] = $result->re_ru;

    // get the images
    $im_codes = json_decode($result->im);
    foreach ($im_codes as $im) {
        $required[] = 'http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/m' . $im . '.jpg';
    }

    fputcsv($csv_file, $required);
}
```

Generated output:

```
10,"Rue Basslé",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYESF.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES7.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES9.jpg
114,"Rue Hanoteau",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ABZGY2.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ABZGY5.jpg
31,"Rue Brasserie Gillieaux",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-9ZXJLP.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-9ZXJLS.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-9ZXJMS.jpg
198,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AELG3S.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AEVHX6.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AEVHX8.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AEVHXA.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AEVHXC.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AEVHXE.jpg
334,"Rue de Gozée",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AF4H3P.jpg
,"Rue de la Ferrée",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AG9EJM.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AG9EJP.jpg
11,"Rue de la Station",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-A6UCCX.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-A6UCCY.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-A6UCD2.jpg
47,"Rue de la Plateure",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFXL43.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFXL4H.jpg
5,"Chaussée de Lodelinsart",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AF3GDJ.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AF3GDL.jpg
72/74,"Rue d'Acoz",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ABDCWC.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ABDCWJ.jpg
314,"Parc Résidentiel Le Bosquet",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ACMC4J.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ACMC4S.jpg,http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-ACMC4X.jpg
111,"Rue Chausteur",http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFWCFT.jpg
```

Comment: When i use your code, I need to output in the same time

    [""WEBB-AFYESF"",""WEBB-AFYES7"",""WEBB-AFYES9""] 

to CSV as

    "http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYESF.jpg",
    "http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES7.jpg",
    "http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES9.jpg"
I can't with your code

Comment: I don't know, how to do it :(

Comment: This is really another question. The question you asked has been answered

Answer (score -1):

I need to output in the same time

```
[""WEBB-AFYESF"",""WEBB-AFYES7"",""WEBB-AFYES9""]
```

to CSV as

```
"http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYESF.jpg",
"http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES7.jpg",
"http://photos.notmaison.be/photos/mWEBB-AFYES9.jpg"
```